# How can I plot String Array of addresses on MapView and show markers?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mkmapview

This is for one String whereas I have an array of addresses.

```
var address = self.address
        var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
            }
        })
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop to traverse your array and drop markers accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

This would do.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    let addressArray = ["address1", "address2"]
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var count = 0

    @IBAction func PlotAddresses(sender: AnyObject) {
        plotAddressesInMap()
    }

    func plotAddressesInMap() {
        if count < self.addressArray.count {
            let address = addressArray[count]
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                print("Address = \(address)");
                if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
                }
                print("Count = \(self.count)")
                self.count += 1
                self.plotAddressesInMap()
            })
        }
    }
}
```